# Find Duplicate and give key identifier to the data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the simple table below:

[image]

Script for which is given below

```
    CREATE TABLE SimpleTable
(
    Name varchar(100),
    Postcode  varchar(100),
    VATNumber Varchar(100),
    SANNumber varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.SimpleTable
(
    Name,
    Postcode,
    VATNumber,
    SANNumber
)
VALUES
(
    'UMESH', -- Name - varchar
    '431001', -- Postcode - varchar
    '4567', -- VATNumber - Varchar
    '9090' -- SANNumber - varchar
)
INSERT INTO dbo.SimpleTable
(
    Name,
    Postcode,
    VATNumber,
    SANNumber
)
VALUES
(
    'UMESH', -- Name - varchar
    '431001', -- Postcode - varchar
    '9094', -- VATNumber - Varchar
    '9090' -- SANNumber - varchar
)
INSERT INTO dbo.SimpleTable
(
    Name,
    Postcode,
    VATNumber,
    SANNumber
)
VALUES
(
    'Prajakta', -- Name - varchar
    '431001', -- Postcode - varchar
    '9094', -- VATNumber - Varchar
    '5555' -- SANNumber - varchar
)

INSERT INTO dbo.SimpleTable
(
    Name,
    Postcode,
    VATNumber,
    SANNumber
)
VALUES
(
    'Prajakta', -- Name - varchar
    '777777', -- Postcode - varchar
    '9094', -- VATNumber - Varchar
    '5555' -- SANNumber - varchar
)

INSERT INTO dbo.SimpleTable
(
    Name,
    Postcode,
    VATNumber,
    SANNumber
)
VALUES
(
    'Prajakta', -- Name - varchar
    '777777', -- Postcode - varchar
    '9094', -- VATNumber - Varchar
    '5555' -- SANNumber - varchar
)
INSERT INTO dbo.SimpleTable
(
    Name,
    Postcode,
    VATNumber,
    SANNumber
)
VALUES
(
    'Ramesh', -- Name - varchar
    '12345', -- Postcode - varchar
    '9089', -- VATNumber - Varchar
    '4534' -- SANNumber - varchar
)
```

What I want the output is 
if there is any single match on anything like Name,Postal code,VAT number or SAN number ,Then I want to assign one key identifier to it.
So far I have tried below query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by NAME) AS KeyIdentifier,st.Name,st.Postcode,st.VATNumber,st.SANNumber
FROM dbo.SimpleTable st
GROUP BY NAME,st.Postcode,st.VATNumber,st.SANNumber
HAVING COUNT(NAME)>1 AND COUNt(st.Postcode)>1 AND Count(st.VATNumber)>1 AND Count(st.SANNumber)>1
```

But this gives me single record with one identifier
But What I want is like this

In general if there is any match either on name,postal code,VAT number or SAN number assign the key identifier to that record. Like wise if you see the result key identifier 3 is assigned because VAT is matching like this.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: enter code here]

[image]

Comment: Seriously, didn't under stand what you want. Try explaining it in a different way

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    single.name,
    Postcode,
    VATNumber,
    SANNumber

FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name) as id ,
        name
 FROM 
     (SELECT distinct name 
      FROM SimpleTable) as names
 ) as single INNER JOIN
(SELECT PostCode,
        name,
        VATNumber,
        SANNumber 
 FROM SimpleTable) as nfo
ON single.name = nfo.Name
```

try this it might be what you want.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15ae2/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements do not entirely make sense and I dont know exactly what you will do with the results...  This query does group the key identifiers on the four fields, hopefully this can get you started.

```
;
With cteAssign As (
Select  Dense_Rank() OVER (Order By Name) AS KeyIdentifierName,
        Row_Number() OVER (Partition By Name Order By Name) AS KeyOrderName,
        Dense_Rank() OVER (Order By PostCode) AS KeyIdentifierPostCode,
        Row_Number() OVER (Partition By PostCode Order By PostCode) AS KeyOrderPostCode,
        Dense_Rank() OVER (Order By VatNumber) AS KeyIdentifierVatNumber,
        Row_Number() OVER (Partition By VatNumber Order By VatNumber) AS KeyOrderVatNumber,
        Dense_Rank() OVER (Order By SanNumber) AS KeyIdentifierSanNumber,
        Row_Number() OVER (Partition By SanNumber Order By SanNumber) AS KeyOrderSanNumber,
        st.Name,st.Postcode,st.VATNumber,st.SANNumber
    From dbo.SimpleTable st
)
Select * From cteAssign Order By KeyIdentifierName  -- By Name
--Select * From cteAssign Order By KeyIdentifierPostCode    -- By PostCode
--Select * From cteAssign Order By KeyIdentifierVatNumber   -- By VatNumber
--Select * From cteAssign Order By KeyIdentifierSanNumber   -- By SanNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
create table #SimpleTable(
    name varchar(50),
    Postcode varchar(50),
    VATNumber varchar(50),
    SANNumber varchar(50),
)

insert into #SimpleTable values( 'MAHESH', '101114', '4567', '9090' )
insert into #SimpleTable values( 'MAHESH', '101114', '9094', '9090' )
insert into #SimpleTable values( 'pajacta', '101114', '9094', '5555' )
insert into #SimpleTable values( 'pajacta', '7777', '9094', '5555' )
insert into #SimpleTable values( 'rammer', '12121', '9089', '4534' )
insert into #SimpleTable values( 'pajacta', '7777', '9094', '5555' )

select * from #SimpleTable

MAHESH  101114  4567    9090
MAHESH  101114  9094    9090
pajacta 101114  9094    5555
pajacta 7777    9094    5555
rammer  12121   9089    4534
pajacta 7777    9094    5555

;with cte as(
    select
        a.name  
    from
        #SimpleTable  a
    group by
        a.name
    having
        (count(distinct a.Postcode) > 1) 
        or (count(distinct a.VATNumber) > 1) 
        or (count(distinct a.SANNumber) > 1)
),
cte1 as(
    select distinct * from #SimpleTable
)
select
    KeyIdentifier = row_number() over(partition by a.name order by a.name ),
    a.name, 
    a.Postcode, 
    a.VATNumber,
    a.SANNumber 
from
    cte1  a
    left join cte on (a.name = cte.name)

1   MAHESH  101114  4567    9090
2   MAHESH  101114  9094    9090
1   pajacta 101114  9094    5555
2   pajacta 7777    9094    5555
1   rammer  12121   9089    4534


drop table #SimpleTable
```